# ggplot2 - how to adjust stat_bin and stat to use calculation of a different variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

The goal is to generate a "histogram" of `x` where the bars are `sum(y)/count(x)`, where `y` is another variable describing the data. The point is to use `ggplot` binning to do the grouping part. **I do not want to calculate the binning myself and then perform the calculation.**

example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

k <- runif(1000)
k <- k[order(k)]

y <- c(rbinom(n = 500, size = 1, prob = .05), rbinom(n = 500, size = 1, prob = .95))

w <- data.table(k, y)
```

so a `plot(w$k, w$y)` gives

[image]

so theoretically what I am looking for looks like this:
`ggplot(w, aes(k)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(sum(y)/count)))`

but it generates this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want but sum(y) is going to be the same for **all** bars.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
set.seed(13434)
k <- runif(1000)
k <- k[order(k)]
y <- c(rbinom(n = 500, size = 1, prob = .05), rbinom(n = 500, size = 1, prob = .95))
w <- data.table(k, y)


    constant_value <- sum(w$y)

    ggplot(w, aes(k)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(constant_value/count)))
```

gives exactly the same plot as

```
    ggplot(w, aes(k)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(sum(w$y)/count)))
```

## Edit:

Not sure if this helps you, here I use the same binwidth (30) as ggplot2s default:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    w %>% 
        arrange(k) %>% 
        mutate(bin = cut_interval(1:length(k), length=30, labels=FALSE)) %>% 
        group_by(bin) %>% 
        summarise(mean_y = mean(y),
                  mean_k = mean(k),
                  width = max(k) - min(k)) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(mean_k, mean_y, width=width)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        labs(x="k", y="mean y")
```

which makes this figure:

[image]

Comment: appreciate the dplyr approach, but due to other considerations I would like ggplot to do the calculation withing the bandwidth

Comment: So did you find a solution where you can have variable values for `sum(y)` or `sum(w$y)` ? Because I don't see how this is possible using `ggplot2::geom_histogram`. But I would like to learn!

Comment: if I come up with something legible I would post it here